# DotNetNuke | is license required

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-5

I am planning to create content management site using dotnetnuke for client....
do I need to purchase any license for development purpose...

After development when I deployed content management site on production (client hosting environment) do client need to purchase any sort of license to use it for commercial purpose?

please advise

Comment: Licensing and legal issues are off topic in SO. You could ask DNN if you need one. And as an anecdotal subjective experience: make sure you know what you're getting into with DNN.

Comment: Is making suggestive negative comments allowed?

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't need any licenses for DNN - neither for dev nor for production, it's open source :).